# Pergunta sobre Release Management da Microsoft

Tags: debate, suporte

Galera, queria saber se uma sobre *Release Management* suporta a implantação de projetos em *Windows Forms* faria parte do escopo do SOpt ?

Preciso de saber se ele suporta fazer o Gerenciamento de Implantação, pois fiz uma pergunta sobre liberação de software por clientes, e o *RM* é uma ótima ferramenta de liberação!

Então a pergunta seria: Posso pergunta se o *RM* suporta *WinForms* no SOpt mesmo ?

Se caso não for, por acaso alguém tem um bom artigo sobre como ele funciona ? O que eu preciso ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu acho que é totalmente *on-topic* (mesmo eu não entendendo bem o que você quer com isto). Quando é assim, pergunta e vê o que acontece. Se der problema, fecharem e você não concordar, você traz pra cá.

Comment: Vale ressaltar que se não for *on-topic*, também não seria conveniente perguntar no meta!